# CanvasCamera for iOS PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, html, cordova

First of all, I'm really new to Cordova and Xcode and I'm trying to create an inline QR Code scanner from and HTML 5 app (or at least see if it's possible with this plugin).

I'm trying to follow the instructions from https://github.com/daraosn/Cordova-CanvasCamera and I am unsure what format or how to edit the config.xml in my project.

The instructions say:
"Edit your config.xml and add CanvasCamera into your Plugins list." but i dont know what this means or what format it should follow.

Also, when I add the plugins to the Plugin folder in the project, Xcode throws an error saying:
"'NSAutoreleasePool' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode".

I know that getUserMedia isnt support in Safari/iOS so it's pushing the boundaries a bit. If all else fails, i'll just use the input type=file and access the camera that way.

Answer (score 1):

That plugin you reference looks severely dated. My best guess is, for your config.xml, add:

```
<plugin name="CanvasCamera" />
```

once you copied the files into your directory per those instructions.

Also, you could check out https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin.  You can install it by running "cordova plugin add https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin.git && cordova prepare".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Steve, yeah it was pretty old and unstable. Pretty bad FPS on ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin (http://scandit.com) which is much better than what i was originally trying to achieve.

The only downside is that it's a premium service ($200/month), however the upsides are: super easy to install, is really really fast at decoding (doesn't need to focus, shade doesn't matter), available on plenty for platforms, good documentation.

Another point was that it is a fullscreen camera plugin, which actually works better than inline, what we initially wanted.

Hope it helps anyone else.